# iPhone InApp Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've some question about Apple billing system. Can I specify custom price in app, for example price can be downloaded from my server and it can be changed in the feature.

Thanks.

Comment: You means change the price as per your require? You want to change price from trier to your custom price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Server Product Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html)